# Overriding Foundation Top Bar in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I am trying to override the settings for the top bar in the foundation framework. So far tried a lot of combinations without success. My current settings are below. It doesn't seem to be picking up the changes

Gemfile

```
    # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'foundation-rails'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
```

foundation_and_overrides.scss

```
$topbar-bg-color: #e6e6e6;
$topbar-bg: $topbar-bg-color;
```

I eventually plan to move it out of the overrides file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was as simple enough as adding some custom SCSS

```
   .top-bar {

  background: #615f5e;

}
```

Though I am still not sure where those variables in the overrides file are used.